# React Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `Component`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React component that requires the react-router in separately from app.js.

I have a component that does a redirect using the mixin Router.Navigation like so:

```
var React = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router');

var Searchbar = React.createClass({

  mixins : [Router.Navigation],

  searchTerm: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) {
      return;
    }

    this.context.router.transitionTo('/someRoute/search?term=' + e.currentTarget.value)
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="searchbar-container">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." onKeyDown={this.searchTerm} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Searchbar;
```

I tried to write a test for this but ran into a wall. Apart from the fact that I'm unable to test that transitionTo works as expected, I've also encountered this error message in my Jest tests:

**Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `Searchbar`.**

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the warning and bonus question, how I can test that the transition works as expected?

I've done research into this and this conversation on Github here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/400 is the closest I've found to the problem. It looks like I need to export the router separately but that seems like a lot of overhead to just run component tests without the warning a la https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/testing.md

Is that really the way to go?

Comment: None, that I've managed to make work but I'm still working on this. It's not ultra urgent as they are just warning messages but they are annoying. I'll get this sorted though.

Comment: Hi @Tom I finally found a solution as BinaryMuse's last paragraph got me on the right track. I posted my own answer with the code.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know mate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 0.13 of React Router, the mixins `Navigation` and `State` were deprecated. Instead, the methods they provide exist on the object `this.context.router`. The methods are no longer deprecated, but if you're using `this.context.router` explicitly you don't need the mixin (but you need to declare the `contextTypes` directly); or, you can use the mixin, but don't need to use `this.context.router` directly. The mixin methods will access it for you.

In either case, unless you render your component via React Router (via `Router#run`), the `router` object is not supplied to the context, and of course you cannot call the transition method. That's what the warning is telling you—your component expects the router to be passed to it, but it can't find it.

To test this in isolation (without creating a router object or running the component through `Router#run`), you could place a mocked `router` object on the component's context in the correct place, and test that you call `transitionTo` on it with the correct value.

Comment: Also this answer is deprecated : https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md 
Like many others in the community, we misunderstood the "mixins are going away" sentiment. Mixins, along with React.createClass are not going away any time soon, and definitely not until ES6 classes have better answers to replace what mixins do (like decorators).

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer gave me the solution. See my own answer for more details.

Comment: new upgrade guide is here https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md

Answer (score 4):

Because the `router` relies heavily on the lesser known `context` feature of React you need to stub it like described [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13-compat/docs%2Fguides%2Ftesting.md)

```
var stubRouterContext = (Component, props, stubs) => {
  return React.createClass({
    childContextTypes: {
      makePath: func,
      makeHref: func,
      transitionTo: func,
      replaceWith: func,
      goBack: func,
      getCurrentPath: func,
      getCurrentRoutes: func,
      getCurrentPathname: func,
      getCurrentParams: func,
      getCurrentQuery: func,
      isActive: func,
    },

    getChildContext () {
      return Object.assign({
        makePath () {},
        makeHref () {},
        transitionTo () {},
        replaceWith () {},
        goBack () {},
        getCurrentPath () {},
        getCurrentRoutes () {},
        getCurrentPathname () {},
        getCurrentParams () {},
        getCurrentQuery () {},
        isActive () {},
      }, stubs);
    },

    render () {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
  });
};
```

And use like:

```
var stubRouterContext = require('./stubRouterContext');
var IndividualComponent = require('./IndividualComponent');
var Subject = stubRouterContext(IndividualComponent, {someProp: 'foo'});
React.render(<Subject/>, testElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my Jest file for a complete answer to this question. BinaryMuse’s last paragraph got me on the right track but I find code examples always the most helpful, so here it is for future reference.

```
jest.dontMock('./searchbar');

describe('Searchbar', function() {
  var React = require('react/addons'),
      Searchbar = require('../../components/header/searchbar'),
      TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

  describe('render', function() {
    var searchbar;

    beforeEach(function() {
      Searchbar.contextTypes = {
        router: function() {
          return {
            transitionTo: jest.genMockFunction()
          };
        }
      };

      searchbar = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <Searchbar />
      );
    });

    it('should render the searchbar input', function() {
      var searchbarContainer = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(searchbar, 'searchbar-container');

      expect(searchbarContainer).toBeDefined();
      expect(searchbarContainer.props.children.type).toEqual('input');
    });

  });

});
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not Jest-specific but it might help people coming across the same problem.
I created a class to wrap `router` `context`.

Then in your test just add
`<ContextWrapper><YourComponent/></ContextWrapper>`

It can be useful to wrap other things like `ReactIntl`.

Note that you will lose the possibility to use shallow rendering but that's already the case with `ReactIntl`.

Hope that helps someone.

---

ContextWrapper.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
    childContextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    getChildContext () {
        return {
            router: {}
        };
    },

    render () {
        return this.props.children;
    }
});
```